# Import client across multi-realms Keycloak

Tags: keycloak

I want to config Keycloak to work across multi-tenancy / realms, so how to config client to work across multi-realms?

Comment: It's not clear what is your problem. Client belongs to the realm, so it really can't work accross multi realms. in theory you can use Identity Brokering between realms, but that's not a "import client" - it's different concept.

Comment: According to https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2016-July/006928.html client can work across multi-realms but we need to add client with the same id and secret, so w need to just import client instead GUI creation

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ that's not *import* of one client into multiple realms. That's *duplication* of one client into multiple realms.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a client application that is multi-tenant aware and every tenant is mapped to a different realm, different clients within a single realm, or a combination of both, you may want to implement a [KeycloakConfigResolver](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/14.0.0/adapters/oidc/adapter-core/src/main/java/org/keycloak/adapters/KeycloakConfigResolver.java) in your client application and keep sepearate configs per client.

Assuming you are using Java and OIDC, check out the [adpater documentation for multi-tenent support](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#_multi_tenancy).